# laravel add amount to the next parent in loop

Tags: php, laravel

I have a loop which will get the parent of a user but only up to the max user rank which is `Senior`.
My question is how to add the amount assigned to a user rank if he is not/skipped in the loop or no record found for that rank.

The code below is working and inserting the earnings to each rank, because the parents ranks are present in the database. But what if some is not, I want to add the amount of that user who is not in the loop-to the next rank.

Imagine that it is looping through the parent until it gets to `Senior`, that's how it works.

The rank are in order

```
Junior
Premium
Advanced
Senior
```

Ranks with their corresponding amount value

```
Junior - 100
Premium - 150
Advanced - 200
Senior - 250
```

Users table

```
+------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  id  |  username  |  parent_id  |   rank     |
+------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  1   |   john     |    NULL     |  Senior    |
|  2   |   jane     |    1        |  Advanced  |
|  3   |   josh     |    2        |  Premium   |
|  4   |   joey     |    3        |  Junior    |
|  5   |   jade     |    4        |  Basic     |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Code

```
$user_id = 5; // jade
$parent_id = 4;
    
// call the function to insert the earnings

self::insertEarnings($user_id,$parent_id);


private function insertEarnings($user_id,$parent_id) {
 
    if ($parent_id > 0) {
        
        $user_parent = $parent_id;
        
        $has_parent = true;
        
        // start iteration
        while($has_parent == true){
            
            $account = User::where('id',$user_parent)->first();
            
            $amount = 0;

            if ($account->rank == "Junior" ) {
                
                $amount = 100;
                    
            } elseif ($account->rank == "Premium") {

                $amount = 150;
                // for example this user/parent does not exist the amount(150) for him will be added to the next rank which is the Advance

            } elseif ($account->rank == "Advanced") {

                $amount = 200;
                
            } elseif ($account->rank == "Senior") {

                $amount = 250;
                
                // set to false to stop the iteration
                $has_parent = false;
            }

            $earnings = new Earnings;
            $earnings->user_id = $account->id;
            $earnings->amount = $amount;
            $earnings->save();
                    
            $next_parent = User::where('id',$user_parent)->first();
            $user_parent = $next_parent->parent_id;

            if($user_parent == 0){
                $has_parent = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

The `$user_id` is not used in this example, but there's a use to that that didn't included in the question because that is not the main problem.

Comment: So you want to add amount `200` (which for Advance and Jane's ranking) to username `john` because it hasn't the parent id. If this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @sssurii yes if that is the case. when `Advanced` user is not present in the loop or he does not exist in the records

Comment: Pardon! If you want assign a parent user with amount equal to amount of his child's rank, Only when parent user has no parent ID OR his rank doesn't exists in rank subset?

Comment: yes @sssurii you are correct

Comment: anyone want to help?

Comment: I'd recommend storing your 'amounts' in a separate table, and create eloquent relationships to access them.